# WordPress page not rendering for public on desktop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I have a wordpress woocommerce website using elementor plugin.

**Website URL** - https://cratuscart.com/

The website doesnt render on the desktop but it renderd on mobile and tablet. On desktop I only see a white screen and the basic HTML structure when I inspect.

The website only renders on the desktop when I am logged in to the admin.

This issue started when I moved the hosting to another webhost.

Can anyone suggest what can I do to fix it.

Comment: Hi, Try saving permlinks option and try again, also check if your .htaccess file is fine, and check if you have some js causing conflict. Also you can debug disabling plugins one by one to see if some of theme is causing conflict. Or switching to the default theme and try again. Regards.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help the issue got fixed by deactivating and then activating the plugin.